# Using prisma in a dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

I have a node express project using prisma as the ORM.  I want to be able to run `prisma migrate` and `prisma generate` in the dockerfile.  However these commands do not seem to work in a dockerfile.  My question is - is it possible to automate prisma migrations in a dockerfile without user intervention?
Thanks,

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by these commands do not seem to work in a docker file? You can run `npx prisma migrate` and `npx prisma generate` just like any other random arbitrary shell command inside docker (eg: `npm run start`). If you could kindly provide the docker image you're using and perhaps what the exact problem or issue you're facing, I might be able to give more details.

Answer (score 1):

The last part of my Dockerfile is:

```
#CMD ["yarn", "start"] #commented out
CMD ["bin/startup.sh"]
```

I no longer do `yarn start`. Instead I call a script and inside I do the stuff I need:

```sh
# --- bin/startup.sh ---

npx prisma generate
npx prisma migrate deploy
yarn start
```